# Cron Job not working in plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-cron

I have written a plugin that will convert posts to excel format and then email the .xls to an email id. I can make it work with when function is declared in functions.php but does not work with function defined in plugin file.

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'xls_func_hook1' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'xls_func_hook1' );
}

add_action( 'xls_func_hook1', 'sendxls1' ); //senxls1 is a function in functions.php
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'xls_func_hook2' ) ) {

  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'xls_func_hook2' );
}
add_action( 'xls_func_hook2', 'export2excel' );
```

The full code is at [Here](http://pastie.org/4435356)

Comment: when you say not working ... what do you mean? Have you read that wp-cron does not always run exactly as you plan it

Answer (score 3):

The cron event needs to be registered on the plugin activation hook like so:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_cron' );
function activate_cron() {
    wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'the_function_to_run' );
}
```

The `the_function_to_run` defined in the wp_schedule_event needs to be your function that you want to run at the time interval.

***Note***: When you say something is *"Not Working"* it is really hard to answer.  Please be more specific to get better answers.

Comment: i added this as you mentioned    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_cron' );
function activate_cron() {
    wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'export2excel' );
}     . By not working i mean that it does not send an email. @Daimen can you please elaborate how it doesn;t work the way we want it to work.

Comment: If i register the cron in plugin activation hook, then it will run once atleast when the plugin is activated after deactivation?

Comment: WP-Cron is not the same as server cron. You can have a schedule, but wp-cron needs to be triggered by someone visiting your site. As the WP-Cron function only runs when there is a page request see also http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/insights-into-wp-cron-an-introduction-to-scheduling-tasks-in-wordpress/

Comment: Does that mean if a wp_cron is scheduled after every hour, it actually counts 60 visits and then runs? @Damien

Comment: No it just means that if no one visits your site for 3 hours then your cron will have missed running 3 times and will not run until someone visits your site.  Basically WordPress does not load anything unless it gets a visit.

Comment: I have added a cron job and i am re-loading the page myself, so that should make it run?

Comment: you're wrong, first because scheduled event doesn't need to be registered on plugin activation; then your code is wrong because the 3rd parameter in wp_schedule_event is not a function but the hook name

Answer (score 0):

@Chris_O is half-right and your code is half-right, see [this documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event). On plugin activation, you register a custom action hook (so that your plugin doesn't repeatedly register duplicate events). Then you attach your cron function to that custom hook.

Comment: IMO, would be better if you reproduced the code from the Codex in your Answer.

Comment: @brasofilo And what happens when WordPress updates their documentation? Yet more stale information.

Comment: It's not "their" documentation, it's [ours](http://codex.wordpress.org/Special:Contributions/Brasofilo). And you are making a statement based on the current state of affairs, if there's an update in the docs, your Answer won't make sense anymore. ::: Anyway, it's just my opinion.

Comment: It is "theirs" as in the group of active wordpess doc maintainers. That you are one of them does not negate that. I think linking to specific doc page will remain more salient than duplicated code ever will, even if that function is deprecated. There are thousands of sites out there that continue to perpetuate old hacks and misguided advice. I don't think stack exchange sites should be amongst them.

Comment: Walf Sorry, but @brasofilo is right on that. SE policy is to keep everything in questions and answers to prevent link rot. Later users can (and will) improve your answer if it gets outdated.